# Make kitty terminal emulator to use the current working directory for new windows

Tags: configuration, terminal-emulator, kitty

Say I have a window in kitty and press `ctrl+shift+enter` to open a new window.

The new window always uses `~/` as current working directory. I'd like the new window to use the same working directory that the last window used.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your `kitty.conf`, instead of using `map ctrl+shift+enter new_window`, use `map ctrl+shift+enter new_window_with_cwd`.

Couldn't find this in the documentation but the author mentions it in [this issue](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty/issues/928).

Comment: It's somewhat hard to find, but it is in https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/conf.html#keyboard-shortcuts .

Comment: I used `map kitty_mod+enter new_window_with_cwd` and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: not working in ubuntu though - new window opens in home folder

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/conf/#window-management):

> You can open a new window with the current working directory set to
> the working directory of the current window using:
>
> ```
> map ctrl+alt+enter    launch --cwd=current
> ```

Works for me in Lubuntu 20.4:

```
~$ kitty --version
kitty 0.23.1 created by Kovid Goyal
~$ ack 'map ctrl\+shift\+enter' .config/kitty/
.config/kitty/kitty.conf
27:map ctrl+shift+enter launch --cwd=current
```

Answer (score -1):

You could save $PWD into a file and in your .bashrc change to the corresponding folder.

The following code is not a complete implementation but a proof-of-concept (which contains issues (e.g.: it does not handle parameters for cd)).

in .bashrc add following lines:

```
save_and_change_folder() {
  if [[ -d "$PWD/$1" ]]; then
    echo "$PWD/$1" > cat /home/<user>/.last_folder_visited
  fi
  cd "$1"
}
alias cd="save_and_change_folder"

if [[ -e "/home/<user>/.last_folder_visited" ]]; then
  cd "$(cat /home/<user>/.last_folder_visited)"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking more of something limited to kitty configuration options. Your solution is a good idea, but for me it's perhaps too coupled to bash configuration.